# Query data on spring boot with CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, utf-8

I am working with Spring boot project and have a problem :(

I used :

```
public interface Comment1ServiceRepository extends CrudRepository<Comment1, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT comment1.comment_id,comment1.contribution_id,comment1.user_id,comment1.comment,comment1.photo_id,comment1.stamp_id,comment1.like_count,comment1.update_date,comment1.create_date,comment1.delete_flg,comment1.stamp_place FROM comment1 INNER JOIN contribution1 ON comment1.contribution_id = contribution1.contribution_id WHERE contribution1.location = ?1 LIMIT ?2, ?3", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Comment1> findByPlace( String location, Integer offset, Integer limit);
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM comment1  WHERE comment LIKE %:name%", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Comment1> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

I provide a parameter for location which is "村上" (so no UTF-8 string)
and when I query it doesn't return data (0 row) eventhough it exists in the database

But when I query with a UTF-8 string (for example: "America"), everything works fine.

I don't know why Spring-boot doesn't work for non UTF-8.

Comment: That query does not look good to me .. isnt comment a varchar?